# D3 - X Axis labels are overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm create a line chart using D3 v4 and the labels X are overlapping.

```
// Add the X Axis
var xAxis = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x)
.tickValues(data.map(d=>d.date))
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d/%m %H:%M")))
.selectAll("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("x", 9)
.style("text-anchor", "start");
```

The full code is here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsjnzey2/4/)

Comment: Find the overlapping labels, and then move them. [Finding the overlapping labels](https://jsfiddle.net/tsjnzey2/6/).

Comment: Hi @Bhavik! I am using your example to try update the labels using this:

    rect1.right = rect2.left;

But is not working!

Comment: In really @Bhavik, I would like to generate line chart on D3 like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55643259/line_chart_excel.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Do not use given tick values. The data points near the right end of the chart are too close to each other for doing this. Just remove this line

```
.tickValues(data.map(d=>d.date))
```

Show the exact times in a tooltip if they are important.

Comment: Thanks for reply @tormi-reinson!
But I can not remove this line, because I want to plot only labels that contains data.
If I remove this line, other values that is not in data array will be printed on X Axis.